# MongoDB connection initialisation delay on certain Windows 10 devices

Tags: networking, mongodb, connection, timeout

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58856620/mongodb-connection-initialisation-delay-on-certain-windows-10-devices

**System info**

OS Name: Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise

OS Version: 10.0.17134 N/A Build 17134

**MongoDB Version**

MongoDB 4.2.1 x64 Windows.

**Overview**

When forming a connection to a standalone mongod instances

PS C:\MongoDB> .\mongod.exe --dbpath C:\data

A significant delay, 10-25 seconds, is seen forming the connection between the client and the server.

PS C:\MongoDB> .\mongo.exe 127.0.0.1:27017

We have excluded the theories of the problem being related to the firewall and proxy.

**Analysis**

Aligning the verbose logs of both the client and server shows a delay when processing the admin command.

(> = server, ~ = client)

```
~ MongoDB shell version v4.2.1
~ connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/admin?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
~ 2019-11-14T02:23:29.803-0800 D1 NETWORK  [js] creating new connection to:127.0.0.1:27017
> 2019-11-14T02:23:29.806-0800 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:60413 #1 (1 connection now open)
> 2019-11-14T02:23:29.806-0800 D3 EXECUTOR [listener] Starting new executor thread in passthrough mode
~ 2019-11-14T02:23:29.806-0800 D1 NETWORK  [js] connected to server 127.0.0.1:27017
> 2019-11-14T02:23:46.635-0800 D2 COMMAND  [conn1] run command admin.$cmd { isMaster: 1, hostInfo: "REDACTED:27017", client: { application: { name: "MongoDB Shell" }, driver: { name: "MongoDB Internal Client", version: "4.2.1" }, os: { type: "Windows", name: "Microsoft Windows 10", architecture: "x86_64", version: "10.0 (build 17134)" } }, $db: "admin" }
> 2019-11-14T02:23:46.635-0800 I  NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:60413 conn1: { application: { name: "MongoDB Shell" }, driver: { name: "MongoDB Internal Client", version: "4.2.1" }, os: { type: "Windows", name: "Microsoft Windows 10", architecture: "x86_64", version: "10.0 (build 17134)" } }
> 2019-11-14T02:23:46.635-0800 D3 NETWORK  [conn1] Starting server-side compression negotiation
> 2019-11-14T02:23:46.635-0800 D3 NETWORK  [conn1] Compression negotiation not requested by client
> 2019-11-14T02:23:46.635-0800 I  COMMAND  [conn1] command admin.$cmd appName: "MongoDB Shell" command: isMaster { isMaster: 1, hostInfo: "REDACTED:27017", client: { application: { name: "MongoDB Shell" }, driver: { name: "MongoDB Internal Client", version: "4.2.1" }, os: { type: "Windows", name: "Microsoft Windows 10", architecture: "x86_64", version: "10.0 (build 17134)" } }, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:257 locks:{} protocol:op_query 0ms
~ 2019-11-14T02:23:46.636-0800 D1 NETWORK  [js] connected connection!
~ Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("a1c87b79-d721-4d57-b3f9-c17aa9db41cd") }
~ MongoDB server version: 4.2.1
```

**Overlaying the network comms captured Wireshark**

```
Time               Source                Destination           Protocol Port        Length Info
02:23:29.805873    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      60413,27017 56     60413 → 27017 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=65495 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
02:23:29.805954    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      27017,60413 56     27017 → 60413 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=65495 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
02:23:29.806041    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      60413,27017 44     60413 → 27017 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=525568 Len=0
02:23:29.816470    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             SSL      60413,27017 368    Continuation Data
02:23:29.816569    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      27017,60413 44     27017 → 60413 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=325 Win=525568 Len=0
02:23:46.636463    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             SSL      27017,60413 301    Continuation Data
02:23:46.636562    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      60413,27017 44     60413 → 27017 [ACK] Seq=325 Ack=258 Win=525312 Len=0
02:23:46.637297    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             SSL      60413,27017 105    Continuation Data
02:23:46.637364    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      27017,60413 44     27017 → 60413 [ACK] Seq=258 Ack=386 Win=525312 Len=0
02:23:46.637991    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             SSL      27017,60413 111    Continuation Data
02:23:46.638079    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      60413,27017 44     60413 → 27017 [ACK] Seq=386 Ack=325 Win=525056 Len=0
02:23:46.646216    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             SSL      60413,27017 108    Continuation Data
02:23:46.646297    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      27017,60413 44     27017 → 60413 [ACK] Seq=325 Ack=450 Win=525312 Len=0
02:23:46.646984    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             SSL      27017,60413 1186   Continuation Data
```

With particular reference to the following 2 packets

```
02:23:29.816569    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      27017,60413 44     27017 → 60413 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=325 Win=525568 Len=0
02:23:46.636463    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             SSL      27017,60413 301    Continuation Data
```

it looks as if mongod has a delay of circa 15 seconds between the initial response and sending the continuation data.

**Question**

Have you experienced this issue and what can be done to minimise the delay?